# EC2 Instance(Windows) recurring schedule by using Auto Scaling to Start/Stop the same instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I want to start and stop an ec2 instance daily at a given time. I am using Auto scaling module for doing the same. But it is terminating the instance instead stopping (shutting down) the instance and while starting the instance each time launching a new instance. Auto scaling is taking inputs as image ID of the instance, AWS access key ID and AWS secret key. I want to start and stop same instance everyday. How can it be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways in which you can achieve this. Yes auto scaling terminates the instances and doesn't stops the instances.

**With Auto-Scaling** :

- You need to modify your code / app logic to handle the difference between stop & terminate instance. You need to make the application deployed in your EC2 instance to be stateless.

**Without Auto-Scaling** :

- You can run a separate process / scheduled script which can run either on-premises or inside EC2 which fires the script. The Script should have the instance ID and start and stop.

PS : Looking at your scenario, I suggest to pick the "With-Auto Scaling" approach; I am not sure how it would differ or where does it affect because of the instance behavior or STOP vs. TERMINATE.

Comment: Hi Naveen I have set all the required environment variables and finally "as-cmd" is working. Now I am using the following code:

Comment: as-put-scheduled-update-group-action   --name "schedule-start"   --auto-scaling-group "test-asg"   --min-size 1   --max-size 1   --recurrence "24 14 * * *"
as-put-scheduled-update-group-action   --name "schedule-stop"   --auto-scaling-group "test-asg"   --min-size 0   --max-size 0   --recurrence "17 14 * * *"
So how can i modify my code so that it stops the instance rather terminates, can you please suggest me?